# Creating an HTML hidden control from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, hidden-field

I have a Masterpage application where I want to create a hidden field
`<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnField" runat="server" Value=""/>`

in order to get the client-side time, so I am following an option suggested ["How can i get timezone of the client machine?"](http://forums.asp.net/post/1647824.aspx). However, since my application is a Masterpage app, my question is: where should I create the hidden control in the aspx file (in the .master file... or in the child aspx page or should I create it on the page_load event on the .cs page) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the markup that you have in your question in your .master page. Make sure that it is located inside the `<form>` tag.

Your script (also in the masterpage) would look like this:

```
document.getElementById("<%=this.hdnField.ClientID%>").value = "...";
```

Comment: How would I call it to set the DateTime value in window.onload event?

Comment: @Knagis... I could not get "<%=this.hdnField.ClientID%>" to work, but I got document.getElementById("ctl00_hdnField") to work. Would it be considered wrong to use this method?

Comment: @Csharp that's because it should have been `<%= hdnField.ClientID %>`. That's how you get the generated .NET ID.

Comment: @MikeSmithDev... thanks for the reply. Though I am curious, would I risk crashing the app if I used "document.getElementById("ctl00_hdnField")".

Comment: It won't crash your app if you leave it where it is in the MasterPage, but if you move that control around to outside the master or within another control, like a asp:Panel, then the "ct100_hdnField" would not work, it would need to be updated to whatever .net generated for it's ID.  See this article http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031710-1.aspx