# Accessing value of a hidden field on Masterpage from codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages, hidden-field

In a follow up to my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15682764/72324), I want to get the value of the hidden input field from the child page codebehind.

I tried `HtmlInputHidden hdnID = (HtmlInputHidden)Page.Master.FindControl("ctl00_hdnField");` but I get a "null" value.

[image]

A snippet of the Masterpage is:

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal2" runat="server" Text=" : Logistics Management" />
    </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link href="~/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ScriptCssContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    ......
    ......
    ......
        <div id="container">
        ....
        ....
        ....
                <div id="content" style="z-index:0;">
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnField" runat="server" Value=""/>
                ....
                ....
                ....
                        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

                        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

On my Child aspx page, I have this javascript block:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var newDate = new Date();
    var hidField = document.getElementById("ctl00_hdnField");

    if (hidField != null)
        hidField.value = newDate.toLocaleString();
}
```

When I "Add Watch" to

> document.getElementById("ctl00_hdnField")

the value is correct.

**Question:** How would I access the value inside hdnField control, from codebehind?

Comment: Are you trying to find the control from the masterpage's codebehind or the child page's codebehind?

Comment: the child page's codebehind

Comment: Just make a readonly property named `Master()` in your child page that returns the masterpage instance and reference it in your child page like `Master.hdnField`

Comment: I would note that you would probably need to go into your designer file and make `hdnField` public.  But, that's the cleanest and simplest solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So change it FROM

`HtmlInputHidden hdnID = (HtmlInputHidden)Page.Master.FindControl("ctl00_hdnField");`

TO

`HiddenField hdnID = (HiddenField)Page.Master.FindControl("hdnField");`

It's just a casting thing - notice `HtmlInputHidden` changed to `HiddenField`. You also don't need the `ct100_` part - this is just so the HTML rendered element has a unique ID.

The control on your page is an asp.net control, not a generic HTML control.

You would use `HtmlInputHidden` if you put a generic `<input type="hidden" />` in your HTML.

Comment: Unbelievable !!! This was a big fat brain fart on my side. Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: By the way, if you're planning on using any Javascript to interact with the form elements and your using .net 3.5 or higher then also set the `ClientIDMode=Static` property - this will prevent .net from adding all sorts of nonsense to your ID's.

Comment: ClientIDMode = Static is a .net 4 feature, correct? This project is in  VS2008 (ClientIDMode does not show in VS2008 HTML intellisense)

Comment: Sorry, yes, .net 4 and up... :)

Answer (score 3):

You should create a property in Masterpage which wrap the HiddenField.

```
public String HdnFieldValue
{
get
{
    return hidField.Value;
}
set
{
    hidField.Value = value;
}
}
```

And in page code behind you can access it like this:

```
((YourCustomMaster)Page.Master).HdnFieldValue
```

If something is not clear please ask me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to prefix the hidden field's ID with `ctl00_`, just use the normal ID:

```
(HtmlInputHidden)Page.Master.FindControl("hdnField");
```

Comment: error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField' to type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputHidden'.

Comment: I just used 'HtmlInputHidden' because that's what you had at the top of your own example. Obviously you should be casting to HiddenField as Darren suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
if (Page.Master.FindControl("hdnField") != null)
{
    String myValue = (HtmlInputHidden)Page.Master.FindControl("hdnField").value;
}
```