# How to disable certain checkbox items in checkboxlist2 if a specific list item from checkboxlist1 is checked?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have these JavaScript function that runs every time on every pageload and postback. How do I change the settings of this function to make it run only during the 1st load of the webpage and not every postback?

Do I change $(window).ready(function ()? OR I set it in my aspx.cs file page load?

```
$(window).ready(function () {
    $("#Checkboxlist1 :checkbox").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $("#Checkboxlist1  :checkbox[value='Select All']").removeAttr('disabled');
    $("#Checkboxlist1  :checkbox[value='Select All']").prop("checked", true);
    });
```

Comment: Why are you mixing javascript and jquery. **window** is for javascript and for jquery you need `$(document).ready(function () { })`;

Comment: For making such decision you need to set some thing in hidden field onec it is not a postback in your page load method. then using same hidden field value you can make decision to make a call or not. Simple basics of asp.net .

Comment: @Suprabhat hi, plz don't answer a question with a question like that; just explain. ;)

Comment: @Wazz Thanks and  @newtoasp you need to do a simple thing just add all you placeholder content inside an **update panel**. All function and javascript code mentioned under `$(document).ready();` won't execute at post back. They will only execute during normal **page load**.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden field to your page lets say hdnIsPostBack.Then in page_load of page
check

```
if(IsPostBack)
    hdnIsPostBack.Value = "true";
```

Then in you funciton of javascript chek the same.

```
if($("#hdnIsPostBack").val()=="true")
   // here your code goes
```

Comment: `hdnIsPostBack` Id will change if used a master page.

Comment: Definitely sir then you  will have to learn first using hidden fields with master pages http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689859/accessing-value-of-a-hidden-field-on-masterpage-from-codebehind

Comment: <input type="hidden" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" /> use this by this id will remain same

Comment: Thanks man I very well know that and I wasn't saying you were wrong but you should have shared the same what you have just said to me in previous comment to the OP.

Comment: Ok so kind of miscommunication hence if you got your answer then mark you question other wise senior mentors will be looking in to the same question.

Comment: Ok, It was a miscommunication but one last thing i just want to put up and don't have any hard feeling for that `<input type="hidden" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" />` won't support **clientidmode** only `<asp:HiddenField Id="?" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>` has the privilege of using **ClientIDMode**.

Comment: Once you add a normal control as runat server in you page then it will be treated as a control class  and will be available in your designer. cs . there you can check get and set both are available for hidden fied hence same can be added in mark up !! try it will work !!

Comment: OK, will surely check that out if it's possible to add from there as i have hardly ever used designer.cs. While writing a markup **ClientIDMode** isn't recognized in non asp.net control thus i had to rely on asp.net control for that. Well Thanks mate :)

Comment: if you got your answer then mark you question other wise senior mentors will be looking in to the same question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
    function pageLoad()
    {
    
    //Write your code here .it run only during the 1st load of the webpage
    
    }
     window.onload = pageLoad;
    </script>
```