# Hidden value not getting on server side in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have hidden field on Master page and i am setting value to hidden field from client side on menu click like below.

```
 $('a').click(function (e) {
        var Menuid = $(this).attr("id");
        $('#<%=HTMLHiddenField.ClientID %>').val(Menuid);
    });
```

But on post back i am trying to get value on server side but it show empty value. My server side code is below.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
       string hdnvalue =Convert.ToString(HTMLHiddenField.Value);
 }
```

Comment: Where is the hidden field located? Is it placed inside ASPX page or a master page? Also that you should retrieve it on postback-related events, not on `Page_Load` event.

Comment: Hidden field located in Master page

Answer (score 0):

form will only post those values to server side which resides inside it, any value outside of the form will not be posted to server side. it looks like that your hidden value is outside of the current form being posted to server check it and if you want to post that value to server side keep it into your form.

Comment: it is in form tag on master page

Comment: check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689859/accessing-value-of-a-hidden-field-on-masterpage-from-codebehind)